# socket.io Connection Problem node.js Hosted on Domain

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I have tried a million different ways to connect via socket.io.

I keep getting the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss:/example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=CiLGqnUNiDKvOsreAAAW' failed:
```

server.js

```
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 443;

const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  key:fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem', 'utf8').toString(),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem', 'utf8').toString()
}
const httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app)
const io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId)
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
    })
  })
})

httpsServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

scripts.js

```
const socket = io.connect('https://example.com:443')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {})
const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true
const peers = {}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: true
}).then(stream => {
  addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)

  myPeer.on('call', call => {
    call.answer(stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
      addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
  })

  socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
    connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
  })
})

socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
})

myPeer.on('open', id => {
  socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
  })
  call.on('close', () => {
    video.remove()
  })

  peers[userId] = call
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play()
  })
  videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

room.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script>
    const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>"
  </script>
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.2.0/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #video-grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
      grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    }
    
    video {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="video-grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I connect via socket.io? I'm working with my own domain and using cpanel and running node.js.

I am trying to follow the tutorial at: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Zoom-Clone-With-WebRTC

Comment: Hi, on the client connection can you try `io()` instead of `io.connect..` and which version socket.io you installed? v2.0.3 as shown in the github link or some other version?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried io() with no luck. And yes the installed version is the one from the github link.

Comment: Well I've just tried it on my computer and it seems like it's working on localhost. This problem might be about server but instead of your code. I couldn't see any problems with code bdw :)

Comment: Thank you for checking! I had better luck with localhost as well. Do I need to do anything to make a port on my server accessible?

Comment: Well I'm sorry I can't really help with server-side stuff :(